# Magento 2.3 - Can not hide account navigation links based on customer groups

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, xml, myaccount

I'm trying to hide account navigation links based on customer groups. In order to hide the links, I have installed a module https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-hide-account-sidebar-tabs by creating different block files for the corresponding links but unfortunately, the links are not hiding.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account\WishlistLink" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wish List</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true" />
                <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account\OrderLink" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-new">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account1\AccountLink" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block file:

```
<?php

namespace MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account;

class AccountLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $customerGroup;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,
        array $data = []
     ) {
         $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
         $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup;
         parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, $data);
     }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $responseHtml = null; // need to return at-least null
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); // Current customer groupID
            //Your Logic Here
            if ($customerGroup == '2') {
                $responseHtml = parent::_toHtml(); // Return link html
            }
        }

        return $responseHtml;
    }
}
```

If you see the logic in the block, I have written a condition to show the link only if the customer group belongs to the group-id 2, if not it should be hidden. In my case, the link displays even in group-ID 1.

I'm not sure what am I missing. I'm trying this to work from a couple of days but not a success.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your **XML** file content with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account\WishlistLink" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wish List</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account\OrderLink" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true" />
            <block class="MageHelper\HideSidebarTabs\Block\Account\AccountLink" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link-custom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

After changing this please run below commands in CLI once

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me!!